# Breeze navigation property is not observable

Tags: odata, breeze

I don't understand something about collection navigation properties.

First, I went through metadata debug, all checks out. As per documentation, I expected the navigation collection property to be observable, e.g. I can get the collection via

```
Foo.Bar() // bar is KO observable array
```

However, I can't get it working like that.

My query:

```
new breeze.EntityQuery()
    .from('Classes')
    .where('ClassId', '==', id)
    .expand('LessonOfClasses')
```

Results to:

```
[
   {
      "$id":"1",
      "$type":"Model.Class, Model",
      "ClassId":24,
      "LessonOfClasses":[
         {
            "$id":"2",
            "$type":"Model.LessonOfClass, Model",
            "class_lesson_id":30,
            "class_id":24,
            "lesson_id":40,
            "Class":{
               "$ref":"1"
            },
            "Lesson":null
         },
         // other instances of LessonOfClass...
         ]
      // other properties of Class...
    }
[
```

Which looks fine to me. However, when I run the query the result is:

```
var classObject = data.results[0];
classObject.LessonOfClasses // returns normal array
classObject.LessonOfClasses() // error:  not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out when knockout isn't available as a dependency, Breeze results to using plain JSON objects.

The problem is I'm using knockout as a require.js dependency and the global **ko** reference wasn't set.

```
requirejs(['knockout'], function(ko) {
    window.ko = ko;
})
```

Breeze is looking strictly for **ko**, as opposed to durandal which I think looks for **knockout**.

Comment: You'll find an example of configuring a Breeze+Knockout app for Require.js in the ["Todo-Require" sample discussion](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-require).

Comment: Per Ward's link - I found it specifically looks for a require module name "ko". If you name it something else, like knockout, which I had to to keep typescript typedefs happy, you need to "alias" it lke this - map: {
            "*": {
                "ko": "knockout"
            },
     }